# Share data with multiple spring application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have 1 main spring boot application and 2 dependent spring boot applications. Dependent app load some data(settings, and so on) from main app on start. Some external service may change this data in main app and dependent app should reload this data. Is there some library or framework.

Comment: What do you mean by dependent spring boot applications ?

Comment: It is just logical relationship. This application is a search services which get requests find data in some external services, get some prepared data from main app, combine all this data and return result.  In this app there is no database.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 solutions:

1. Always retrieve data from every requests. I don't think this is your case since you have loaded them on the beginning to avoid this solution.
2. Refresh the initial data after some amount of time (cron job).
3. Main application acts as micro-service orchestrators and inform all its dependant application that their cache may be invalid. Every dependant application answer this request by refreshing their cache.

For solution number 2 take a look at spring boot [@Scheduled annotation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/). For example you can refresh the data every 5 minutes @Scheduled(fixedRate = 300000).